# Import statement in jade/pug

Tags: javascript, pug

Is it possible to use import statement directly in "script." tag in jade file ?

This doesn't work but throws no error :

```
script(src="../js/plugin/a.js")
script.
    import a from "../js/plugin/a.js"
    a.useFunctionHere();
```

EDITED : And is it possible to use pass variable from js client-side to jade view ?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible, because browsers do not support `import` at this time, although you could look at using webpack and some sort of `pug-loader` tool that allows you to `require('/jsfile.js)`, but I would just use babel or weback and babel-loader and import into your main script file.

It is also not possible to pass variables from the client side javascript to the jade view because the jade view is rendered server side before it is sent to the client, unless you're talking about a secondary request, which then you would pass any parameters to you supplied by the client (such as by a form submit) as the `local` object in the jade `render()` function. This would also be possible if you did a url like `.com/myview/:type/` or `.com/myview?type=myviewtype/` (be sure to sanitize your inputs...)